# Short-term visit to USA as an Indian Citizen - which visa to get?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens

I am an Indian citizen holding a work and residence permit in Spain and currently living in Spain.

Which visa I need to visit USA for a short term?

Comment: What would be the purpose of your visit? That defines the type of visa you will need.

Answer (score 3):

Your status in Spain won't have any influence on the visa you need to enter the USA, which will depend on the purpose of your trip (what you plan to do in the US). The most common visa in your situation are the [B types visa](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visitor.html), intended for regular short-term business or leisure visits.

Comment: @pnuts How so? I am not suggesting a change to the question or anything. He still needs to double-check on the website that he fulfills the conditions but I am providing a solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: I would argue that @Relaxed gave all the information that could be given for this question, as the question was lacking information about purpose of visa, etc. The OP is probably not aware of the fact that this is actually important, so Relaxed added this information.

Comment: @pnuts That's a rather contrived interpretation of the link-only answer rule. You could conceivably want to close the question for lack of research or because the OP isn't very explicit on the purpose of his trip. But until then it's silly to look for pretexts to object to an answer that fully addresses it. It is not a comment and is entirely self-contained. Incidentally, I do provide more information than the name of the visa as I address one non-trivial issue raised by the question (namely whether being a resident in Spain changes anything).

Comment: @pnuts That's why I mentioned the purpose and wrote “regular short business or leisure visits”. Ideally, the OP would provide more details but anybody doing a concert or joining a ship would mention it so it's almost certainly not the case. Explicit is better but we don't have to be deliberately obtuse when reading less than stellar questions.